# Know of a good way to clean a string in .net to be used in Javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am creating a javascript confirm message in my asp.net code:

```
deleteButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete client " + clientName + "')");
```

The problem here is that the client name can have apostrophes and other problematic characters.

Does anyone know a *good, simple* way to clean the variable "clientName" so that I can safely use it in the javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(clientName)

Comment: Thanks ifwdev!  I was expecting a cool regex (which I am sure is out there), but I had no idea this method existed in the framework.  Very nice.

Comment: I kenw about this for object serialization, to get JSON objects out of plain old CLR objects, but never thought of using it for this purpose...nice!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it in .net but rule number one with user input is not to clean, but to **escape** it.

Otherwhise users won't be able to have " in their usernames (might not be so common but in other situations, like this response to your question i had a very legitmate reason to include a ")

Comment: Good point Erik, looks like Nicolas put the code below.  Very relevant when not using names for sure!  I learned two things from one post, today is a good day...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've thought of this, but the .Replace()function is about as simple as it gets.

```
deleteButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete client " + clientName.Replace("'", "&_#39" + "')");
```

Comment: I did David, but curiosity had the better of me and just wanted to see what other cool solutions were out there.  Surprisingly there wasn't a good thread when I searched the Web but StackOverflow seemed like a good place to start one to get some ideas.

Comment: For my similiar situation (passing some data to an ammap from asp.net) this was the only answer that worked...

Answer (score 1):

To get a little fancier:

```
    public static string ToJavascriptString(this string str)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> replace = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        replace.Add("'", @"\'");
        replace.Keys.ToList().ForEach(s => str = str.Replace(s, replace[s]));
        return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SecurityElement.Escape(string s)
```